# Deploying Website on Azure using repository

Tags: azure, hosting, bitbucket

I am using the repository way of hosting a website on Azure. The domain/url has been created and has also been connected to my Bitbucket repository. The problem is when I click the deploy button under the "Deployment Source" tab, All of the other indicators show that I am successful except for the last one. The last one has the red warning icon and reads "Running deployment command...". This error is in the way of being able to access my project on the internet.

Comment: You can take a look at the console to see what the specific error is (with the `View log` link besides the "Running deployment command..." message).

Comment: It indicates that I am missing the "Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" file and  "System.Web.Http.Owin" are these important files? I noticed that they are in my Visual Studio file but cannot find them in the repository.

Comment: Aren't they installed via NuGet packages in your project? If so, they should be present when deploying from your repo. If not, you should add them through NuGet.